# Как уменьшить размер .apk файла в Embarcadero XE 7

Tags: android, c++, c++builder, embarcadero

Пишу программы под *Android* в *Embarcadero* (не ругайте) из-за отсутствия свободного времени.
Учу *С++*, но проблема в том, что *.apk* файл, создаваемый в *Embarcadero*, занимает где-то 8 мегабайт.
Есть подозрение, что *Embarcadero* кидает туда интерпретатор.
Как можно уменьшить размер *.apk* файла?

Comment: а может туда добавили картинок пачку? Сколько весит минимальный hello-world?

Comment: @KoVadim, [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2MUZiCu5Qt_aFhUOUNXOTdIUE0/view?usp=sharing). Весит 6,9 Мб

Comment: Это плата за удобство разработки. Но может кто то уже написал свои [KOL & MCK](http://kolmck.net/rindex.htm).